# Why set attribute fails?

Tags: vbscript

Why this fails?

```
set fldr = CreateObject("shell.application").BrowseForFolder(0, "Example", 0, 0).Self.Path
```

but this works:

```
fldr = CreateObject("shell.application").BrowseForFolder(0, "Example", 0, 0).Self.Path
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the [Set Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4afksd44%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) is not for assigning string variables:

> To be valid, objectvar must be an object type consistent with the object being assigned to it.

This, for example, would work:

```
Set objFldr = CreateObject("shell.application").BrowseForFolder(0, "Example", 0, 0)
strFldrPath = objFldr.Self.Path
```